# The meaning of 'wake' in this sentence

Tags: meaning

**A storm of hail hammered down on the carport, leaving chunks of ice in its wake.**

What is the meaning of '*wake*' in that sentence? I don't really understand, since English isn't my first language.

Please explain it in simple way.

Comment: "Wake" in the sense of the disturbed path of water behind a boat.

Answer (score 2):

Definition 3 in [Merriam Webster's entry for the word](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wake):

> noun
>
> 1 : the track left by a moving body (such as a ship) in a fluid (such
>   as water) broadly : a track or path left
>
> 2 : aftermath sense 3

Answer (score 1):

“Wake” can mean the waves that a boat makes behind it (example: “The jet-ski’s wake disturbed the fishermen.”). It can also refer more generally to something’s consequences. Like how the waves are the ‘consequences’ of the boat, in your sentence, the “chunks of ice” are the consequences of the storm. I hope this helps.

Comment: Jonah, there was already an answer covering the points you make. We generally discourage answers that add no value to our site. I encourage you to read [answer] and take theEL&U [Tour]. :-)